# Java System statements outside code block

Tags: java

My understanding is, that any statement in Java should be in a code block.
But I see in below code that `System.getenv();` is not placed in a code block. But if I put a `System.out.println()` below it, the compiler complains. Is `System.getenv()` here treated as declaration rather than a statement?

```
package gov.ssa.epa;

public class AdvJ {

    private static final Map<String, String> INVALID_FILTER_KEY = System.getenv();

    System.out.println("hello");

    public static void main(String[] args)  {


    }
}
```

Comment: Static assignments of that type are legal. It's no different from `private static int x = 5;` Any given arbitrary statement will probably not be.

Comment: Inline initializations are permitted outside of code blocks, but `System.out.println("hello");` isn't an initialization statement

Comment: [The Java™ Tutorials:  Initializing Fields](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html)

Comment: for all that is scared learn to format your code correctly, if you did that, you would see why this is as it is.

Comment: This is the opposite of the duplicate question: rather than asking "why can I *not* use statements outside methods", OP asks "why am I allowed to use statements". Voting to re-open. As usual, if a better duplicate shows up, please tag me in a comment, and I will be happy to re-close the question.

Answer (score 0):

`System.getenv()` is not a statement, it is an initialization expression used as part of a field declaration. Field declarations are allowed in the context outside of any method - in fact, that's the only place where fields declarations can go. Initialization expressions are attached to the declarations, so, naturally, they are allowed as well.

`System.out.println`, on the other hand, is not a declaration, so it is not allowed outside of a function or an initialization block.

Comment: I think System.getenv() is a statement. It's just that statements are allowed as part of initialization expressions?

Comment: I did look it up I was just being polite. From wikipedia - *In computer programming, a statement is the smallest standalone element of an imperative programming language that expresses some action to be carried out.* 

Getting the environment would seem to match this description, no?

Some types of statements are assertion, assignment, goto, return and (as in this case) **call**.

Comment: @Sam This is not a statement. Although declaration statements, which declare local variables, are allowed inside methods, and they may look exactly the same, field declarations are not considered statements.

Answer (score -1):

This is because private static final Map INVALID_FILTER_KEY = System.getenv() is a private class instance variable. These instance variables can be used anywhere in the class and are thus declared outside of any method. A variable declared inside a method can only be used in that method. The reason it is having problems when you call System.out.println is because this is actual executable code and for actual code to run, it needs to be inside a method. Consider checking out this tutorial on how it works in java classes https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html